# Restore enigmail private keys from file system

Tags: thunderbird, gnupg, pgp, enigmail

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 17.10 and do want to recover my private pgp keys from an already extracted duplicity backup. How to accomplish this task?

Comment: Do you have the keys for your duplicity backup? Duplicity backups are encrypted, and you need the key to decrypt them...

Comment: yes i do, its already extracted and everything. its just that i dont know how where in that backup my keys are and how to get them into enigmail again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution [here](http://gnupg.10057.n7.nabble.com/How-restore-backuped-gnupg-private-keys-v1-d-td50286.html).

Private keys can be recovered by moving .key files from old to new private-keys-v1.d folder and restarting gnupg.

```
mv ~/backup/home/user123/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/*.key ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/
```

Public keys can be restored from keyservers using enigmails keymanager.